# XCode upload issue with iTMSTransporter

Tags: xcode, app-store-connect

I'm trying to upload my archive to iTunesConnect through xCode but I keep getting this error and I can't find information anywhere about how to resolve it:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> An error occurred while trying to start the iTMSTransporter

I'm not even sure what iTMSTransporter is or why it stopped working. [Screenshot of the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBmpS.png).

Also is there a way for me more detailed logs about the failure somewhere or more generally when xCode fails to upload an archive?

Thanks in advance.

Update: I managed to retrieve the logs and seems like Transporter is crashing due to a stack overflow, is there a way of preventing this?

```
[...]
[2020-01-15 15:40:01 GMT] <main> ERROR: An error occurred while trying to start the iTMSTransporter
java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.spi.DefaultProxySelector.select(DefaultProxySelector.java:207)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.determineProxy(SystemDefaultRoutePlanner.java:94)
    at com.apple.transporter.core.impl.DataCenterRoutePlanner.determineRoute(DataCenterRoutePlanner.java:50)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.determineRoute(InternalHttpClient.java:125)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at com.apple.transporter.JSONService.invoke(JSONService.java:385)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1244)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1203)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1167)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1163)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.keepSessionAlive(WebService.java:1798)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.preProcessResult(WebService.java:1750)
    at com.apple.transporter.JSONService.invoke(JSONService.java:393)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1244)
    at com.apple.transporter.WebService.invokeStandard(WebService.java:1203)
    at
[...]
```

Comment: Did you find any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.. It kind of just resolved itself and I can't say if it's because of something I did or not. It stopped working, I tried again a week later and it worked again. For what it's worth: I tried to uninstall iTMSTranspoter and reinstall it, uninstall/reinstall xCode, install the Transporter app to try and upload the IPA through it instead of through xCode and updated the OS to the latest version.